# Does it matter where to run unit tests from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some tests with RSpec in a spec folder.
If I go to inside the main folder of my Rails project and do a `bundle exec rspec`  all good. They all pass.
But if I go **inside** a specific folder in that spec folder and want to run it like b`undle exec this_file_spec.rb`  then I get errors.

Does it make a difference and we are not supposed to run it like that?

NOTE: In my specs I AM calling some methods that are in a separate helper class in the spec folder. So maybe because I am not in that path for that helper method, it can't find it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where your tests are run from if your tests are independent. I think your tests are dependent on the data setup by a different test. Make sure that your transactional fixtures are enabled.